# Panel.Controls.Add performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, panel

I have a panel which loads in controls depending on the template. The code runs fine but it's a bit slow, the slowness is in the last line of `panel.Controls.Add(control)`

Are there any better ways to do this to improve performance?

```
foreach (var b in template.Blocks)
{
    TemplateBlock templateBlock = (TemplateBlock)LoadControl("TemplateBlock.ascx");
    templateBlock.Template = b;
    blockItems[index].id = index;
    templateBlock.DataBlock = blockItems[index];
    templatePanel.Controls.Add(templateBlock);
    index++;               
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that the Controls.Add line was the one slowing things down?

Comment: It's taking 3.5 seconds to load that ascx file 4 times. If I remove the line that adds it to the panel it takes under 1 second....